# Gurobi thread parameter not properly works with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, gurobi

Tried to use several processes to solve different models in parallel but found out that if the process was set the thread parameter (wanted to set 5 and 5 for two processes considering the default was 16), the program would not properly work that one of them (always the first one) would surprisingly pause for a while (known based on the log). Let the thread parameter default then everything went well.

Is there any advice? Tested on Windows, Gurobi 10.02, Python 3.7/3.9/3.11, and tried with two different PCs. Besides, it properly worked with CPLEX.

```
# always something wrong about this process, but actually another did have the same model just with restricted feasible region
def function():
    with gp.Env() as env, gp.read('1.mps', env) as model:
        model.setParam(GRB.Param.MIPGap, 0)
        model.setParam(GRB.Param.TimeLimit, 900)
        model.setParam('Threads', 5)
        model.optimize()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    pool.apply_async(function)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Logs with setting the thread parameter and note that there was an unusual pause:

```
H    0     0                    2.569286e+12 2.1687e+12  15.6%     -  106s
     0     0 2.1687e+12    0 2005 2.5693e+12 2.1687e+12  15.6%     -  111s
     0     0 2.1687e+12    0 1645 2.5693e+12 2.1687e+12  15.6%     -  900s
```

Logs without setting the thread parameter:

```
H    0     0                    5.835511e+12 2.1687e+12  62.8%     -  180s
H    0     0                    5.757233e+12 2.1687e+12  62.3%     -  182s
H    0     0                    2.326050e+12 2.1687e+12  6.77%     -  185s
     0     0 2.2055e+12    0 1500 2.3260e+12 2.2055e+12  5.18%     -  280s
     0     0 2.2055e+12    0 1478 2.3260e+12 2.2055e+12  5.18%     -  280s
H    0     0                    2.314108e+12 2.2055e+12  4.69%     -  284s
     0     0 2.2056e+12    0 1458 2.3141e+12 2.2056e+12  4.69%     -  301s
```

Comment: Please add more detail; I am unable to reproduce on my system. Also, what kind of Gurobi license do you have?

Comment: @GregGlockner Hi I added codes and logs. It's acadamic license. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There may be something else going on. Can you run your test with Threads=5 but without Python multiprocessing?

Comment: @GregGlockner Sorry for my late reply and you were right. Without multiprocessing it is still cannot work with the thread setting. Something wrong about the model & thread but I don't know why.